# What is meant by "hypothetical" repetitions of a sampling experiment?

Tags: sampling, standard-error

given this definition of standard error:
"the standard error quantifies how much an estimator varies in hypothetical repetition of a sampling experiment"

I just wanted to clarify exactly what we mean by "hypothetical" repetitions:

Is it that when we collect a hypothetical sample of size n, we assume(i.e. hypothesise) that the $X_1,...,X_n$ come from some distribution F, and this is opposed to actually performing and collecting observations $ x_1,...,x_n$ of the variable of interest?

Comment: The word _hypothetical_ comes from the frequentist view of probability. If I claim a coin is fair, $P(\mathrm{H}) = 1/2,$ then I'm claiming that in many hypothetical tosses of the coin I'd get Heads on about half of the tosses. For 10,000 tosses, within $.5\pm .01$ on 95% of such 10,000-toss experiments. This is not taken as a commitment to do a huge number of actual coin tosses.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. This is simply the definition of the standard error.

While *sample standard deviation* tells you how dispersed are the datapoints of *one* sampling experiment, *standard error* tells you how dispersed an estimate would be across *many* sampling experiments. Obviously, you don't repeat sampling experiments, calculate an estimate for every individual sample and then calculate the standard deviation of those estimates; thus they say *hypothetical* repetition of a sampling experiment. You will take one sample, calculate an estimate (such as a sample mean) and then if you want to know how much sample mean would vary if you were to sample again, you can calculate the standard error of sample mean.

The main point to realize is that standard deviation operates on the distribution of a random variable, while standard error operates on the distribution of estimates of a random variable.